# Adding a layer to multiple maps within the same project with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layers, definition-query

Using ArcGIS Pro 3.0

I am looking to apply a definition query on a feature class from a geodatabase and add it as a layer onto 3 maps. My thought was to use a for loop to loop through my maps and add the layer onto each map. The code I have written seems to add the layer 3 times onto the active map, or the map that was last active.

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"filepath\arcpy_statusmapping.aprx")
maps = aprx.listMaps()

for map in maps:
        arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(r"filepath\arcpy_statusmapping.gdb\NOW_Area", "StatusArea", "nowid = '0101010-2011-01'")
```

I have tried a few things to address this to no avail.

```
for map in maps:    
    if map != aprx.activeMap:        
        arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(r"filepath\arcpy_statusmapping.gdb\NOW_Area", "StatusArea", "nowid = '0101010-2011-01'")
    else:
        arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(r"filepath\arcpy_statusmapping.gdb\NOW_Area", "StatusArea", "nowid = '0101010-2011-01'")
```

This code produces no errors but adds the layer to the active map 3 times.
I have fooled around with openView() and closeViews(), but haven't had any luck. I have also tried if/else statements calling each map by its name with the same result as the other code examples I have given.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the **arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer()** line to **map.addDataFromPath()** and put the path in there. So something like this:

```
for map in maps:
   map.addDataFromPath(r"filepath\arcpy_statusmapping.gdb\NOW_Area")
```

From there you could add lines to modify the layer name and apply the definition query, but it solves the issue you had of them all being added to the same map.

Comment: Yes, this solved it, thank you! Do you know why this wont work with the MakeFeatureLayer method? My thought was to use that method because you can apply a definition query and add a temporary layer in one line.

Comment: I think it's because the scope for that method is the active map. Iterating over maps in a list doesn't activate them. I looked to see if for every map you could first change the active map to the map you are iterating on, then applying the method. But I couldn't find a way to change the active map.

Comment: I just read @Hornbydd's comment below. I think maybe the m.openView() method might be worth trying in your original code right before the MakeFeatureLayer() method, because according to the documentation it "Opens and activates a new map view pane in the application."

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```py
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("current")
maps = aprx.listMaps()
for m in maps:
    m.openView()
    m.addDataFromPath(r"C:\Scratch\fGDB_Scratch.gdb\testmultipoint")
```